# Liferay windows-1250 encoding

Tags: html, jsp, encoding, liferay

How can I use Windows-1250 encoding in my portlet? I'm developing a simple portlet in Czech language and can't figure out how to use this encoding.
Example of a label in jsp file: (Social Security Number in Czech)

> RodnÃ© ÄÃ­slo*

should be

> Rodné číslo

tag meta doesn't help

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-2">
```

or

```
<meta charset="windows-1250">
```

or whatever combination...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself the hassle: Go UTF-8 all the way. That's what's recommended for Liferay's default anyway and will take care of all czech characters anyway. And if you have the occasional chinese user signing up for your portal, they'll be able to use the native writing of their name as well. Problem solved.

And go UTF-8 all the way: From Database to frontend. You'll save yourself soooo much future work. Getting encoding wrong is a mess. And having a nonstandard encoding will mess up with all future assumptions of people that touch & configure your portal.